# Login not work for all users - systemd

Tags: systemd, login

I have multiuser mode in my linux and when I try login don't work. 
How to fix it?

From liveos i read journall and I have error:

```
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1288]: user@0.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1288]: user@0.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/lib/systemd/systemd: Permission denied
```

all journall for login as root:

```
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 0.
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting User Runtime Directory /run/user/0...
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain systemd-logind[997]: New session 5 of user root.
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started User Runtime Directory /run/user/0.
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='unit=user-runtime-dir@0 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 0...
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain audit[1288]: USER_ACCT pid=1288 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_localuser acct="root" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain audit[1288]: USER_ROLE_CHANGE pid=1288 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='pam: default-context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0 selected-context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0 exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1288]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain audit[1288]: USER_START pid=1288 uid=0 auid=0 ses=6 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_selinux,pam_selinux,pam_loginuid,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd,pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain audit[1288]: AVC avc:  denied  { transition } for  pid=1288 comm="(systemd)" path="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" dev="dm-2" ino=11163545 scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0 tclass=process permissive=0
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1288]: user@0.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1288]: user@0.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/lib/systemd/systemd: Permission denied
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: user@0.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start User Manager for UID 0.
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='unit=user@0 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Session 5 of user root.
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain login[1274]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user root by LOGIN(uid=0)
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain audit[1274]: USER_START pid=1274 uid=0 auid=0 ses=5 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_selinux,pam_loginuid,pam_console,pam_selinux,pam_namespace,pam_keyinit,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd,pam_unix,pam_lastlog acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/login" hostname=localhost.localdomain addr=? terminal=tty1 res=success'
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain audit[1274]: CRED_REFR pid=1274 uid=0 auid=0 ses=5 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/login" hostname=localhost.localdomain addr=? terminal=tty1 res=success'
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain audit[1274]: USER_LOGIN pid=1274 uid=0 auid=0 ses=5 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=login id=0 exe="/usr/bin/login" hostname=localhost.localdomain addr=? terminal=tty1 res=success'
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain login[1274]: ROOT LOGIN ON tty1
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain audit[1291]: AVC avc:  denied  { transition } for  pid=1291 comm="login" path="/usr/bin/bash" dev="dm-2" ino=11172221 scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0 tclass=process permissive=0
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain audit[1274]: CRED_DISP pid=1274 uid=0 auid=0 ses=5 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/login" hostname=localhost.localdomain addr=? terminal=tty1 res=success'
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain login[1274]: pam_unix(login:session): session closed for user root
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain audit[1274]: USER_END pid=1274 uid=0 auid=0 ses=5 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:session_close grantors=pam_selinux,pam_loginuid,pam_console,pam_selinux,pam_namespace,pam_keyinit,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd,pam_unix,pam_lastlog acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/login" hostname=localhost.localdomain addr=? terminal=tty1 res=success'
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='unit=getty@tty1 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service: Service has no hold-off time (RestartSec=0), scheduling restart.
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Getty on tty1.
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='unit=getty@tty1 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='unit=getty@tty1 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain systemd-logind[997]: Session 5 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Nov 15 12:06:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
```

Comment: have you done anything special with SELinux on this system?  Seems like you have some denials there for systemd trying to start bash.

Answer (score 0):

set SElinux to permissive mode using `setenforce 0` then try again

Comment: [Don't make Dan Walsh cry](https://stopdisablingselinux.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, works.
I try /etc/selinux/config set 'disabled' and works normal. Next:
restorecon -rv /
and set normal /etc/selinux/config
reboot and system works normal